# Simple exercise about linear dependent points and resulting cover.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology, inequality

currently I am reading some proof and the following claim comes up.

Let $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ be a normed vector space. And let $(x_i)^n_{i=1}$ be finite points in $X$ that are linear dependent i.e. one has
$$
x_m = c_1 x_1 + \dots + c_n x_n
$$

then the author claims that for $l > j(|c_1|+ \dots + |c_n|)$ one can construct the following inclusion of open sets in $X$ i.e.
$$
W_{(x_1,\frac{1}{l})} \cap \dots \cap W_{(x_n,\frac{1}{l})} \subset W_{(x_m,\frac{1}{j})}
$$

this should be simple too prove, however I just don't get the right inequality. What I have tried is the following. The condition above is equivalent too
$$
\frac{1}{l} \leq \frac{1}{j(|c_1|+ \dots + |c_n|)}
$$
Take any $y \in W_{(x_1,\frac{1}{l})} \cap \dots \cap W_{(x_n,\frac{1}{l})}$ then one has
$$
|y-x_m| = |y-\sum^k_{i=1, i\neq m}c_i x_i| \leq \sum^k_{i=1, i\neq m} |c_i| |y-x_i| + |y(1+c_1+\dots+c_k)| \leq \frac{1}{l} \sum^k_{i=1} |c_i| + (1+|c_1|+\dots+|c_k|) |y|
$$
Where is where I am stuck since I believe I have no more control about this |y|. The first part has a nice bound, however the second part is problematic. Any hint is helpful.

Comment: When you write $x_m = c_1 x_1 + \dots + c_n x_n$, is $m$ between $1$ and $n$? If so, then $x_m$ is going to be a term on the right hand side. Is the right hand side supposed to exclude the $m$ term? Or is this some kind of typo? Given the problem uses the coefficients of these terms, I think it's important to make this precise.

Comment: Yes, x_m is one of the finite many points $x_1,\dots, x_n$ so it is between 1 and n. This is used in the last line below since one take $|y-x_m| = |y-c_1 x_1 + \dots + c_n x_n - c_1 x_1 - \dots - c_n x_n - x_m | = |y-\sum^n_{i=1, i \neq m} c_i x_i|.$